# How Do I Make My C# Application Install Without Admin Rights?

Tags: c#, installation

Yesterday, I installed Spotify from an .exe file on a Windows 7 computer with a user that didn't have admin rights (limited user). It looks like it installed in the AppData folder and created a shortcut onto the desktop and in the start menu. However, it was also added to the list of installed programs in the Add/Remove Programs section of the control panel, which I didn't think you could do without admin rights.

I really like this method, and would like to apply it to a C# app created in SharpDevelop. What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: +1; Useful question :)  It might be even more useful if you change the title from "like Spotify" to "without admin priveleges"?  IMO you've got a great answer for "Like Spotify", assuming it will work in SharpDevelop and not just VS.  But there might be other alternatives that would be useful to more people (e.g. people already using WiX, NSIS, etc).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is definitely ClickOnce. Under the Build menu, select Publish *YourProjectName* and follow the wizard - you’ll have a ready-to-go installer in /publish in no time that, in my experience, doesn’t require admin rights.

Comment: I concur. ClickOnce is good technology. It also allows you to handle upgrades.

Comment: +1; I opened the Spotify installer in 7-Zip, searched for keywords I found inside that file, and [found this thread](http://serverfault.com/questions/75067/how-to-tell-which-program-is-used-to-create-a-setup-exe-file).  The thread says `Microsoft Visual C++ v6.0 DLL [Overlay]`, which sounds like VS made the installer.  I created a tiny console app, and an installer in VS using ClickOnce, opened up the installer in 7-Zip, and the layout looked quite similar.  So yes, pretty sure Spotify uses ClickOnce.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Unfortunately, I don't believe I can use ClickOnce with SharpDevelop. I'm going to leave this question open for now to try to find a more relevant answer. If that doesn't happen, I'll mark this answer correct.